# Android ToggleButton not reliably receiving state_pressed

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable

I'm attempting to tint a `Drawable` using `DrawableCompat` but for some reason the `Drawable` is not always respecting `state_pressed`

I have a `ColorStateList` which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/yellow" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

I set this on my `Drawable` like so

```
myButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
Drawable drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(myButton.getBackground());
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.color_list));
myButton.setBackgroundDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(drawable));
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

The `ToggleButton` xml is as follows:

```
<ToggleButton
     android:id="@+id/my_button"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1.0"
     style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
     android:background="@drawable/my_nine_patch"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:textOff="@string/none"
     android:textOn="@string/none" />
```

What I'd expect is that when I press down on the button it changes to black and then when I unpress the button it is either yellow or gray as appropriate.

However, initially nothing happens.  When I press the button quickly a number of times it cycles through black, yellow, and gray seemingly at random.

**Interestingly** Even if I call setPressed(true) on the `ToggleButton`, it is still not being changed to black.

Am I doing something wrong with my selector?  Do I need to do some sort of magic incantation with `ToggleButton` to make it work?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having similar issues.