# Pressed State Not Being Selected in ImageButton Tint List

Tags: android, android-view, android-color

I have a view class `TintSelectorImageButton` that applies a tint using `DrawCompat::setTintList`:

```
public class TintSelectorImageButton extends ImageButton{
    // Actual resource values seem to be fairly large and positive, so -1 should be a safe sentinel
    protected static final int NO_TINT = -1;

    public TintSelectorImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray args = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TintSelectorImageButton);
        if(args.hasValue(R.styleable.TintSelectorImageButton_tintList)){
            int colorStates = args.getResourceId(R.styleable.TintSelectorImageButton_tintList, NO_TINT);

            if(colorStates != NO_TINT){
                ColorStateList colorStateRes = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, colorStates);
                Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(getDrawable().mutate());
                DrawableCompat.setTintList(wrappedDrawable, colorStateRes);
                setImageDrawable(wrappedDrawable);
            }
        }
        args.recycle();
    }
}
```

I am providing it a `ColorStateList` through the defined xml property that looks like this one:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:color="@color/sheet_toolbar_disabled"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/sheet_nav_clicked"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/sheet_toolbar_enabled"/>
</selector>
```

Unfortunately, the pressed state is not actually showing when I touch the button, but click events are being passed properly to the provided `View.OnClickListener`:

```
    mPrevSheetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            showSheet(mPrevSheetUid);
        }
    });
```

To get things to work for now, I just took the image and colored it in an image editor and used this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_prev_light_blue"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_prev_disabled"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_prev"/>
</selector>
```

Oddly, the drawable selector reaches the "pressed" state without issue.

Comment: This issue is similar but for a different kind of button:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293880/android-togglebutton-not-reliably-receiving-state-pressed

Comment: Works fine for me using v23.2.0 of support library. You might want to set the default tintMode.
```DrawableCompat.setTintMode(wrappedDrawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);```

Comment: I swapped the colors around, and the `sheet_nav_clicked` color showed fine when assigned to the `state_enabled="false"` state, so there's something different at work.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with a `ColorStateList` change the background of your `ImageButton` to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` or `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`.

For example,

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:src="@drawable/button" />
```